# Routing grpc traffic through HAproxy 1.8

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, haproxy, grpc, http-proxy

I want to achieve L7 load balancing of grpc traffic using HAProxy 1.8 . Since HAProxy only supports L4 routing for grpc traffic, can we read the grpc request as http2 request (as grpc runs overs http2) in HAproxy and route the request based on some custom header of the request.

Or is there any alternate way to achieve L7 load balancing for grpc traffic. I am aware of the `envoy`by lyft, but don't plan on using it.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update on this, HAProxy supports L7 with H2 on both sides since version 1.9, and gRPC works since 1.9.2 (trailers support was required).

Answer (score 0):

For HAProxy to work as a L7 balancer, HAProxy needs speak http/2 to backends. Last time when I asked about this, I was told that http/2 support isn't on the immediate road-map for HAProxy (but incoming http/2 support is)